# How to test a u32string for letters only (with locale)

Tags: c++, unicode, c++11, utf

I'm writing a compiler (for my own programming language) and I want to allow users to use any of the characters in the Unicode letter categories to define identifiers (modern languages, like [Go](http://golang.org/) allow such syntax already).
I've read a lot about character encoding in C++11 and based on all the informations I've found out, it will be fine to use utf32 encoding (it is fast to iterate over in lexer and it has better support than utf8 in C++).

In C++ there is `isalpha` function. How can I test `wchar32_t` if it is a letter (a Unicode code point classified as "letter" in any language)?

Is it even possible?

Comment: The Unicode standard includes guidelines for what characters should be allowed in 'identifiers' in programming languages. C++ is actually specified to follow these guildlines, although support is still spotty in actual implementations. Other than for identifiers and certain literals you don't have to classify characters because you pretty much specify each token exactly.

Comment: Where can I find these guidlines? Is there any C++ function, which checks if the specyfic character can be used in 'identifier' in programming language (according to the spec)?

Comment: Is this question about testing for a valid *C++ identifier character* or a valid *letter character*?

Comment: valid letter character, sorry for confusion. (I want user to be able to use any letter character as part of an identifier in my language), but answer on the second question would be nice to have also :)

Comment: What is "my language"? You need to be more precise about what you mean by "letter". For example, do you want to include *all* of the characters in the Unicode letter categories (see: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/index.htm), or just those considered to be a letter in a particular locale?

Comment: "my language" is my custom programming language, which I'm developing right now. I think I should include *all*  of the characters in the Unicode letter categories, because if somebody will use these characters, than users with other locales, should be able to see and compile it. (I've edited the question to describe better, what I'm trying to do)

Comment: See [UAX #31](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr31/) for the definition of Unicode identifiers.

Comment: You can use ICU or Boost.Locale to convert your string to NFC, then check whether the first codepoint has the property ID_Start and all others have the property ID_Continue.

Comment: Why don't you just stick with ASCII letters here? Even if you only allow Latin1 characters (i.e. ä) you need to normalise beforehand to make it unambiguous, as it can either be the single glyph (http://www.decodeunicode.org/de/u+00e4) or a combination character followed by the diaresis and a. This is also a good reason why UTF-32 doesn't have a real advantage over UTF-8 here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [ICU](http://icu-project.org) to iterate over the string and check whether the appropriate Unicode properties are fulfilled. Here is an example in C that checks whether the UTF-8 command line argument is a valid identifier:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <unicode/uchar.h>
#include <unicode/utf8.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  if (argc != 2) return EXIT_FAILURE;
  const char *const str = argv[1];
  int32_t off = 0;
  // U8_NEXT has a bug causing length < 0 to not work for characters in [U+0080, U+07FF]
  const size_t actual_len = strlen(str);
  if (actual_len > INT32_MAX) return EXIT_FAILURE;
  const int32_t len = actual_len;
  if (!len) return EXIT_FAILURE;
  UChar32 ch = -1;
  U8_NEXT(str, off, len, ch);
  if (ch < 0 || !u_isIDStart(ch)) return EXIT_FAILURE;
  while (off < len) {
    U8_NEXT(str, off, len, ch);
    if (ch < 0 || !u_isIDPart(ch)) return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }
}
```

Note that ICU here uses the Java definitions, which are slightly different from those in [UAX #31](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr31/). In a real application you might also want to normalize to NFC before.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try it and accept the answer than. Could you please additional tell me if you see any downsides in using such encoding in programming language compiler? (I'm talking about using utf8 vs utf32 encoding in compiler).

Comment: @danilo2: I don't see a downside of using UTF-8. UTF-32 only gives you constant-time random access to individual code points, but that is seldom needed.

Answer (score 0):

there is an `isaplha` in the [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/) project. I think you can use that.